# Android Quiz App and how to code for multiple correct answers

Tags: android

I have written a quiz app for students preparing for an English exam.Some of the quiz asks the users to enter the correct answer into an edittext box and their answers are checked against the list of correct answers in a string. Some questions could have two possible answers ( I'd talk to my boss / I would talk to my boss) How do I code for two possible answers.

Comment: How about using Checkbox in such scenario?

Answer (score 0):

You need to compare the values that your students are entering with preset and saved values in your codes, Use `string1.equals(string2)`piece of code, maybe put it in a `if and else` line and ask what to do if true and what to do if wrong, something like this maybe:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
   final TextView tv=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv1);
   final EditText ed =(EditText)findViewById(R.id.ed1);
   final Button btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn1);
    final String argue1="I'd talk to my boss";
   final String argue2="I would talk to my boss";

    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String saver= ed.getText().toString();
          if (saver.equals(argue1)){
               tv.setText("true");
            } else if (saver.equals(argue2)){
              tv.setText("true");
          }else {
               tv.setText("wrong");
         }
        }
    });

        }}
```

I think I didn't quite get what you mean in your comment, but if you mean something like this:

```
 btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String saver= ed.getText().toString();
          if (saver.equals(argue1)|saver.equals(argue2)){
               tv.setText("true");
          }else {
               tv.setText("wrong");
         }
        }
    });
```

Yes, It also works like this, I just checked that out for you...

Comment: Hi Reza and thanks for your reply. I am new to android so i do not understand how to put two arguments into one item on a string array.

Comment: If its not what your looking for, give me a little bit  more detail about your app,... to help you more.